# Swift: Extending functionality of print() function

Tags: swift, xcode, printing

Is it possible to extend the functionality of a Swift function? I would like appnd a single character onto every print() function in my program without having to create a brand new function and renaming every instance of print(). Is it possible to create an extension that will append an '*' onto every print instance?

The purpose of this is to create a way of flushing out all of the extra information that XCODE adds into the debugger. I am using print statements to check on the progress and success of different parts of my code, but XCODE fills in thousands of lines of excess info in seconds that quickly cover up my specific statements.

What I want to do:

```
print("Hello world!")
//Psuedo code:
Extension print(text: String) {
    let newText = "*\(text)"
    return newText
}
```

Output:
    *Hello World!

I will then filter the Xcode debugging output for asterisks. I have been doing this manually

Comment: If this is in Xcode, have you tried just switching to "Target Output" in the debug window rather than "All Output?"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can overshadow the `print` method from the standard library:

```
public func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    let output = items.map { "*\($0)" }.joined(separator: separator)
    Swift.print(output, terminator: terminator)
}
```

Since the original function is in the standard library, its fully qualified name is `Swift.print`

Comment: Is this "overriding"? I think it's just "shadowing"

Comment: Where can I place this function so that it is available in all files? And is there a way to use this function without having to add `items:` in such as `print(items: "Hello")`

Comment: Make a new `.swift` file and place it there. if you are using Swift 2, you don't have to specify the `item:` label. The code won't work with Swift 3 anyway.

Comment: Is there a swift3 solution to this? Because it is xcode8 that is adding all the unwanted extra garbage to the console.... (which seems to be a 'known issue' and is no longer the case with xcode8.1 beta....) My point being, xcode8 and swift3 are like big buddies... This code not working in Swift3 is kinda missing the point. I would love to have a temporary print replacement that works in swift3.... Or maybe I should just go for xcode8.1 beta.... Little unexperienced in the beta-channel, does it replace your stable version of xcode or can the exist next to eachother?

Comment: I just tried this in swift3/xcode 8.3. You can just add a `_` before items. `public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {...}`

Comment: It appears that this leads to prefacing each print command, like `Swift.print("Hello world")`  Otherwise, Xcode throws an error `Use of 'print' nearly matches global function 'print(_:separator:terminator:)' in module 'Swift'...`

Comment: will this work for your entire app or just the one file?

Answer (score 23):

If we want to cover all cases with custom `print` we should create new file for example: `CustomPrint.swift` and then paste this two methods:

***SWIFT 5.1***

`First (according to ThomasHaz answer)`

```
public func print(_ items: String..., filename: String = #file, function : String = #function, line: Int = #line, separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    #if DEBUG
        let pretty = "\(URL(fileURLWithPath: filename).lastPathComponent) [#\(line)] \(function)\n\t-> "
        let output = items.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: separator)
        Swift.print(pretty+output, terminator: terminator)
    #else
        Swift.print("RELEASE MODE")
    #endif
}
```

`and second because the first one does't cover dictionary and array printing`

```
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    #if DEBUG
        let output = items.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: separator)
        Swift.print(output, terminator: terminator)
    #else
        Swift.print("RELEASE MODE")
    #endif
}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 20):

This code working for me in swift 3

```
import Foundation

public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    let output = items.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: separator)
    Swift.print(output, terminator: terminator)
}

class YourViewController: UIViewController {
}
```