# Overriding Swift.print() or sharing function across all modules

Tags: swift, swift3, module

My point is to extend `Swift.print()` function or writing my own custom function `ns_print()` which could be available from all modules **without explicit import**.

Of cause I [saw some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026752/swift-extending-functionality-of-print-function) like

```
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    let output = items.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: separator)
    Swift.print(output, terminator: terminator)
}
```

But it works only inside module it was defined.
I want to share this function across all existing modules.

Is it possible? Any help?

Comment: If you are using modules, then you will just have to declare it in a common module and import that common module everywhere else, to use your custom print function.

Comment: You can put in global to access everywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Extending functionality of print() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026752/swift-extending-functionality-of-print-function)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to override the functionality of `print`? It might help people to suggest alternative approaches

Comment: I need to log all prints output into special file on macOS app

Comment: @ailinykh: In that case you can *redirect* standard output to a file, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680004/redirect-nslog-to-file-in-swift-not-working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible, if you want to use a function from a different module, you have to import that module.

The default `print` function is part of the `Swift` module, which is automatically (implicitly) imported in all Swift files, this is why it's available everywhere without explicitly importing the module.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so is there any way to extend that global `Swift` module?

Comment: @ailinykh there are some approaches you can follow, described in the linked questions from the comments.